# Can gcc linker options change assembler instructions in the compiled binary?

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, compilation, linker

I am wondering if gcc linker options (e.g.: -Wl,*options*) can change assembler instructions in the compiled executable, as this happens if you use certain gcc optimization options? 
Can the difference between using a linker option and not using it be seen when you compare the compiled binaries (e.g. comparing signatures)?

**UPDATE**

To be more precise I want to figure out if [FLIRT](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/in_depth.shtml) signatures change when I use certain linking options during compilation process. These signatures only use library functions for creating the signatures.

Comment: See e.g. `--wrap`.

Comment: @Phillip can you explain that more precisely?

Comment: The man-page has details on the option; it can be used to override symbols, which, at least for C object files, can also change the function's signature.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot sense. The linker can change what assembly instructions in end up in the executable for a number of different reasons without linker options being involved, and GCC optimization options will typically make massive changes to what assembly instructions end up in the executable.

Comment: Are you asking about what changes the hash of the whole binary, or just the actual machine code?  (i.e. are you excluding object-file meta-data like section headers?)  I'm pretty sure you're including different rel32 offsets in jumps and stuff like that, so ordering matters.  If you only cared about different instruction opcodes, that only happens with link-time optimization where code-gen is done/re-done at link time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some linker options, changes can be seen in the produced binary, for example:

- Options to get rid of/keep debugging symbols (`--strip-all`, `--strip-debug`, `--discard-all`)
- Options to get rid of/keep unused sections, e.g. a section containing a function that is never referenced in other sections. These sections can easily be removed. Or to keep relocation sections/content. (`--as-needed`, `--emit-relocs`)
- Options to include one static library or another compatible one (For example library version x.0 vs version x.1)
- The order in which objects and static libraries are placed on the commandline. For example `ld -o foo a.obj b.obj c.obj` and `ld -o foo a.obj c.obj b.obj` will *probably* produce a different binary if a call from a to a function in c is resolved (the offset for the code from c.obj and thus the address of the function in c will *probably* be different)

But even after linking, the signature of a binary could change. For example in Linux, when you optimize binary startup time by running [prelink](http://freecode.com/projects/prelink)

Comment: actually I am only interested in changes in the binary on function level. If specific debugging symbols are modified this won't change the assembly code of functions. Can you imagine a scenario where the assembly code on function basis changes using linker options?

Comment: Yes, calls to other objects might resolve to different offsets/addresses depending on the order of them or the order of static libraries, or different versions of a library.

Comment: but functions within a static library will remain untouched, right?

Comment: @PeterFox No, they'll typically end up varying depending on where they end up in the executable and where other things they refer to end up residing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will see a different checksum on two binaries linked with different linker options--unless the option had no effect, such as when you specify a default option or an option that doesn't change the binary (-print-map).

What are you trying to figure out exactly?  It sounds like you are having problems when you specify certain linker options and you are trying to figure out why.  Tell us more and maybe we can give better assistance.